# The type 'GroupExpandedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0' Xamarin Android Java Bindings for Thoughtbot ExpandableRecyclerView

Tags: xamarin.android, java-binding

I am trying to create Xamarin Android bindings for this library, https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view.

I have added the following to the `Metadata.xml`

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview']/interface[@name='listeners.GroupExpandCollapseListener']/class[@name='models.ExpandableGroup']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">p0_2</attr>`

but i still get the error and gives a warning that the xpath does not match any nodes.

Here is the file and field am trying to match :

namespace Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Listeners {

```
// Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='GroupExpandCollapseListener']"
[Register ("com/thoughtbot/expandablerecyclerview/listeners/GroupExpandCollapseListener", "", "Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Listeners.IGroupExpandCollapseListenerInvoker")]
public partial interface IGroupExpandCollapseListener : IJavaObject {

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='GroupExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupCollapsed' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableGroup']]"
    [Register ("onGroupCollapsed", "(Lcom/thoughtbot/expandablerecyclerview/models/ExpandableGroup;)V", "GetOnGroupCollapsed_Lcom_thoughtbot_expandablerecyclerview_models_ExpandableGroup_Handler:Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Listeners.IGroupExpandCollapseListenerInvoker, ExpandableRecyclerViewBindingsLibrary")]
    void OnGroupCollapsed (global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup p0);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='GroupExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupExpanded' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableGroup']]"
    [Register ("onGroupExpanded", "(Lcom/thoughtbot/expandablerecyclerview/models/ExpandableGroup;)V", "GetOnGroupExpanded_Lcom_thoughtbot_expandablerecyclerview_models_ExpandableGroup_Handler:Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Listeners.IGroupExpandCollapseListenerInvoker, ExpandableRecyclerViewBindingsLibrary")]
    void OnGroupExpanded (global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup p0);

}

public partial class GroupCollapsedEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {

    public GroupCollapsedEventArgs (global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup p0)
    {
        this.p0 = p0;
    }

    global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup p0;
    public global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup P0 {
        get { return p0; }
    }
}
```

}

The duplicate is on this part :

```
global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup p0;
public global::Com.Thoughtbot.Expandablerecyclerview.Models.ExpandableGroup P0 {
    get { return p0; }
}
```

My question is what should my xpath look like in order to avoid the duplicate property definition for `P0`?

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am trying to use the same library?

Comment: Yes i did, let me add as an answer since the xml is just  big

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, when binding java libraries with Xamarin you will need to map the interfaces to events in .Net.

Adding the following into the `Metadata.xml` will map the interface to the events

```
 <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='ExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupExpanded']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">positionStart</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='ExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupExpanded']/parameter[2]" name="managedName">itemCount</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='ExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupCollapsed']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">positionStart</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='ExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupCollapsed']/parameter[2]" name="managedName">itemCount</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='GroupExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupExpanded']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">group</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='GroupExpandCollapseListener']/method[@name='onGroupCollapsed']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">group</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners']/interface[@name='OnGroupClickListener']/method[@name='onGroupClick']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">flatPosition</attr>
```

Comment: Hi...I have the same issue Com.Wikitude.Tracker.IObjectTrackerListener.cs(47,47): Error CS0102: The type 'TargetsLoadedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' (CS0102)  .....I tried to add   <attr path="/api/package[@name='Com.Wikitude.Tracker']/class[@name='ErrorLoadingTargetsEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">P0</attr> but not working

Comment: The `Com.Wikitude.Tracker` needs to be the Java package name not the C# namespace by the way.

Comment: I tried the same...but not working <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.zoho.livechat.android.listeners']/interface[@name='DepartmentListener']/method[@name='onFailure' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='int'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedName">OnFailureEvent</attr>