# CS0102 The type 'X' already contains a definition for 'PageScrolled' Xamarin android binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, binding, aar

Currently trying to bind an aar file.

I've used the following lines to make changes, but to no avail.

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.shopgun.android.viewpager']/interface[@name='CenteredViewPager.OnPageChangeListener']/method[@name='onPageScrolled']"
      name="argsType">Binding_PageScrolledEventArg</attr>
```

After Dongzhi comment, I added the line.

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.shopgun.android.viewpager']/interface[@name='CenteredViewPager.OnPageChangeListener']/method[@name='onPageSelected']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">param1Int</attr>
```

I'm still facing the same error.
The interface is declared inside the class CenteredViewPager
[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the code you provided, mapping the interface to the event needs to be added to the corresponding parameter, and the code you mapped creates a new onPageScrolled method. You can refer to this mapping code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543081/the-type-groupexpandedeventargs-already-contains-a-definition-for-p0-xamarin#:~:text=method%5B%40name%3D%27onGroupExpanded%27%5D/parameter%5B1%5D%22%20name%3D%22managedName%22%3EpositionStart

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT can you please clarify what you mean, I've added the mapping code from the link you shared and I'm still facing the error.

Comment: Anyone also facing this issue should follow read this documentation

https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/wiki/Duplicate-Events