# Xamarin Android Native Binding Conflicts

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm trying to bind a native SDK, I already have the AAR file. However, when I try to bind it I get a conflict error. The type 'AuthenticateEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' (CS0102)

```
    public partial class AuthenticateEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {
        public AuthenticateEventArgs (global::Com.Sdk.Listener.FingerprintListenerReason p0, global::Java.Security.Signature p1, global::Com.Sdk.Callback.IFingerprintCallback p2)
        {
            this.p0 = p0;
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }

        global::Com.Sdk.Listener.FingerprintListenerReason p0;

        public global::Com.Sdk.Listener.FingerprintListenerReason P0 {
            get { return p0; }
        }

        global::Java.Security.Signature p1;

        public global::Java.Security.Signature P1 {
            get { return p1; }
        }

        global::Com.Sdk.Callback.IFingerprintCallback p2;

        public global::Com.Sdk.Callback.IFingerprintCallback P2 {
            get { return p2; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: search [xamarin android native bindings type already contains a definition for](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+android+native+bindings+type+already+contains+a+definition+for&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS950US950&oq=xamarin+android+native+bindings+type+already+contains+a+definition+for&aqs=chrome..69i57.14201j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8),  leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179501/cs0102-the-type-x-already-contains-a-definition-for-pagescrolled-xamarin-and, which leads to [Duplicate Events](https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/wiki/Duplicate-Events).